# MySQL IFNULL ELSE

Tags: mysql, select, ifnull

I have a select statement where I want to make the select conditional like this:

```
IFNULL(field_a, field_a, field_b)
```

so that it checks field a. If a is null then the select would be field b.

Is that possible ?

Comment: Maybe U mixed IFNULL and NULLIF. U need IFNULL: "If expr1 is not NULL, IFNULL() returns expr1; otherwise it returns expr2."

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Use [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT COALESCE(field_a, field_b)
```

COALESCE is an ANSI standard function that returns the first non-null value from the list of columns specified, processing the columns from left to right.  So in the example, if `field_a` is null, `field_b` value will be displayed.  However, this function will return NULL if there is no non-null value from the columns specified.

It's supported on MySQL (I've used it on 4.1), SQL Server (since v2000), Oracle 9i+...

Comment: I support the use of COALESCE as well.

Comment: Such a clear explanation of how the function works... Thanks! Updated the broken link.

Comment: Pretty cool explanation of a function I'm not familiar with! However, for OP's question, [using `IF()` is much more readable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23395407/114558).

Answer (score 90):

and another way to skin that cat (flexible for not just null comparisons)...

```
select if(field_a is not null, field_a, field_b) from...
```

Comment: Best answer. Allow to do `Select if(name is not null, CONCAT('name is : ',name),'');`

Comment: `select IFNULL(column, 'default')` also works. See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14b752/1/0

Answer (score 45):

Yes, but it's just two parameters:

```
IFNULL(field_a,field_b)
```

If `field_a` is not null, it will be returned. Otherwise `field_b` will be returned.

Reference: [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

Answer (score 0):

The question was modified, and it appears some answers are not in sync with the current question.   Lets start over.
there is no *IFNULL*(test, NullCase, notNullCase), but there is a *switch* statement with *else*.   In this example, i did a left join to find if there is a block, so, but I had the same question, because I want a 0 or 1. here is my solution.

select 
CASE 
WHEN person.blocked is NULL THEN 0 
ELSE 1 
END AS isBlocked 
from mytable