# MariaDB insert into new column data from existing column

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i have to create a new column in my SQL db. The new column should have some data from two other existing colums.

I thought this is a simply SQL command, but it doesn't fill the new column with data

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN new_C text;
INSERT INTO table1 (new_C)
SELECT IFNULL (title_1, title_2) from table1;
```

The new column is created, but it is filled with "NULL". Can somebody help me, what i'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: INSERT INTO `table1` (`new_c`) VALUES ([value-1]); this should be your query

Comment: I thought VALUES add single cells to the column, but in my case, there are 1200 lines at the old column title_1. Some cells are filled with NULL, and that's why i used the command "SELECT IFNULL" to get the data of the whole column and if there is a NULL to get the data from title_2 instead. With Values i have to do this command for every single cell?

Comment: yes you need to map which column you want for null column.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215454/mysql-ifnull-else

Comment: Thanks for your help. But unfortunatelly the result is the same. In the new column new_C is NULL in every cell..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually wanted was an `UPDATE` command:

```
UPDATE table1 SET newC = IFNULL (title_1, title_2);
```

As a result of your `INSERT` command you will probably have a lot of rows with only values of newC in them which you will need to delete.

Comment: Great that works! Thank you very much! Do you know why my command didn't work?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer your insert command will create new rows, not update the existing ones.

Comment: Ah okay, now i understand. Thanks for your help and have a nice day